# Android - Shared element transition making recyclerview items small

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide, shared-element-transition

After I start my profile activity with a Shared Element transition on the profile image, items in the RecyclerView are really small. If I don't do this transition then they're fine. Why and how do I fix it?

Here is a gif of the effect: https://gyazo.com/82fb97f0539a2eeea1677a682a1f1d27

My recyclers onBindViewHolder:

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BaseHolder<ProfileItemBinding> holder, int position) {
    ProfileItemBinding binding = holder.getBinding();
    binding.profileItemName.setText(mTitles[position]);
    binding.profileItemValue.setText(mValues.get(position));
    binding.profileItemValue.setSelected(true);
    binding.setViewModel(new ProfileItemModel(mTitles[position], mValues.get(position)));
}
```

How the image is set:

```
    private void initProfileImage(String url) {
    supportPostponeEnterTransition();
    GlideApp.with(this)
            .load(url)
            .dontAnimate()
            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    supportStartPostponedEnterTransition();
                    if (e != null) e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    supportStartPostponedEnterTransition();
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(mActivityProfileBinding.profileImage);
}
```

How I start the activity:

```
    public void onProfileClick(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat
            .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(((MainActivity) mContext), view, "profile_image");
    view.getContext().startActivity(i, options.toBundle());
}
```

My profile items used in Recycler:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="org.imperium.imperious.Pastebin.viewmodels.ProfileItemModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/profile_item_container"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:onClick="@{viewModel::onItemClick}"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profile_item_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:alpha="0.6"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="Username"
                android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <!-- The use of "singeLine" is because Marquee will not work without it. Android bug or me sucking maybe. -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profile_item_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:alpha="0.6"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="http://pastebin.com/cache/img/2/7/9/2487617.jpg"
                android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="Deprecated" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/md_grey_300" />

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

My profile activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="org.imperium.imperious.Pastebin.viewmodels.ProfileActivityModel" />
    </data>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".activities.ProfileActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="128dp"
                    android:layout_margin="64dp"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:onClick="@{viewModel::onImageClick}"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/guest"
                    android:transitionName="profile_image"
                    app:civ_border_color="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <!--

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/app_bar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_check" /> -->

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/profile_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/profile_include"
                layout="@layout/profile_layout" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

My profile layout ( the include in the activity ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_layout_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/profile_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it some more I remembered that I had animations on my LayoutManager which sort of "Scaled up" all added items, which is why it looked like that. For some reason or another it wasn't finishing the animations, but removing them was a good enough solution.